# Cannot get text to wrap around image

Tags: wordpress

I have looked all the over the net and cannot figure why my text isn't wrapping around the image in my wordpress post (link below). It looks fine when i am in the editor but as you can see i am only able to align "Toddler gas pain typically starts with a burning" next to the image then i have a huge gap.

I have followed best practice, etc but somehow i am missing something here.

here is the link to the post i am refering to - https://kowalabands.com/index.php/2017/06/01/toddler-gas-pain-root-causes-prevention/

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best,
Yvan

Comment: First, is it normal that all your text is in h2 or h3 tags ? Wordpress should create p tags around them, i think it will be better with that :)

Comment: I tried switching to p tags but it won't fix it. Really don't know what the problem is ...